# How to close DOJO layout elements programatically

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

This applies to ArcGIS Server JavaScript API 2.4. The [Build Application Layouts](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/inside_dojoLayouts.htm) help file shows how to lay out a page with elements held within separate containers.

**How can I programatically close a Content Pane when the user presses a button?**

For example in [this map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/layout/layout_MapContainerSplitRight.html), how could I close the rightPane div, and have the map expand to fill the vacant space (ie, hide the Table of Contents)?

ESRI are doing it on the [My Map viewer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html) so it must be possible. The X in the top-right of the Details panel contains this markup:

```
<a title="Close" href="JavaScript:esri.arcgisonline.map.main.hideLeftContentPanel();">
    <img border="0" src="images/close.gif">
</a>
```

How can I find out what that button is doing, and would that help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what you want to do is use the [dojox.layout.ExpandoPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/layout/ExpandoPane.html), then you will do a method like this in your :

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('myExpandoPage'), 'resize', resizeMap);
```

This will tell your app to use the resizeMap method each time the pane gets resized. I use this in several of my apps and it works pretty slick, and can be tweaked nicely with css.

Comment: genius, thank you! Out of interest, can you link to any examples where you've used it?

Comment: also, any tips for putting the pane to the right? If I use <div region="right" dojoType="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane"... it correctly shows on the right, and the min/max arrows orient correctly, but the animation is backwards (ie, it minimizes from right-to-left)

Comment: Sorry, the apps that use this are secure/official state apps. And I have always had my task/operation area on the left edge, so I never noticed the sliding method. You might seem here http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781847192684/ch06lvl1sec05 some more information, sorry I can't give you more.

Comment: no problems, you've already made my day